# What metadata could be stored in the IPFS network and what could be collected by modified nodes?

Tags: network, ip, web-service, pii

I'm guessing uploading to [IPFS](https://ipfs.io) also uploads some metadata, which gets shared as well, does this assumption hold any truth? According to [this](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/privacy-and-encryption/#what-s-public-on-ipfs) only content identifiers and node identifiers are in the public.

- Does uploading a file leak any of your PII?
- Does it leak the uploader's IP or is it dependant on how the file was uploaded?
- It is a known danger as [noted here](https://medium.com/pinata/ipfs-privacy-711f4b72b2ea) that modified nodes might for example gather information like uploaded files and their hashes, even requests of files(!) but what about the metadata? Is this information in danger of getting logged too?
- Why isn't IPFS widely used for uploading a file forever?

Comment: wrt your last question, you can make a file available on your own IPFS node, and have it persist there for as long as you want.  Other nodes may copy your file, but they can also delete the file (e.g. to free up space) at any time, and there is nothing that you can do to force other nodes to store your file indefinitely.  So, the only way to ensure that the file remains available on IPFS 'forever' is to run your own node.

Comment: @mti2935 oh, I thought the main idea of IPFS is that once you upload it stays there forever. It's even the case if you upload it through a 3rd party provider?

Comment: That would be nice.  But, in the end, someone has to pay for all that storage.  See https://medium.com/pinata/the-ipfs-cloud-352ecaa3ba76 for an interesting read on this subject.

Comment: @mti2935 Thanks for the link. I'm guessing hosting a node is not anonymous at all, right?

Comment: There would be nothing to hide the IP address of your node.  It's not like TOR.